# Remove df rows when given ID not preceded by one set of values, or followed by other set of values

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a df that contains various items. Using below, `ID` should contain items from the subsequent lists in any order. So either `A` or `B` should precede `X` or `Y` and then followed by either `C` or `D`.

What I'm hoping to achieve is **when X or Y isn't preceded by `A` or `B` or followed by `C` or `D`**, then notify through a statement and remove the offending rows altogether.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({   
    'Time' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5],             
    'ID' : ['A','Y','C','B','X','D','B','X','A','Y','D','Y','D'],                 
    })

items_before = ['A','B']

items_after = ['C','D']

specific_items = ['X','Y']

# Notify when no preceding item 
for line in df[(df['ID'].isin(specific_items) & df['ID'].shift(1).isin(specific_items))].iterrows():
print(f'No item found for: Time {line[1].Time}')

# Notify when no subsequent item 
for line in df[(df['ID'].isin(specific_items) & df['ID'].shift(-1).isin(specific_items))].iterrows():
print(f'No item found for: Time {line[1].Time}')
```

Current output:

```
    Time ID
0      1  A
1      1  Y
2      1  C
3      2  B
4      2  X
5      2  D
6      3  B
7      3  X
8      4  A # C or D is missing here
9      4  Y
10     4  D
11     5  Y # A or B is missing here
12     5  D
```

Intended output:

```
No subsequent item found for: Time 4
No previous item found for: Time 5

    Time ID
0      1  A
1      1  Y
2      1  C
3      2  B
4      2  X
5      2  D
6      4  A 
7      4  Y
8      4  D
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need test all three masks togeher for consecutive values:

```
#if necessary first filter only matched rows by all joined values
df = df[df['ID'].isin(items_before + items_after + specific_items)]

m1 = df['ID'].isin(items_before) & df['ID'].shift(-1).isin(specific_items) & df['ID'].shift(-2).isin(items_after)
m2 = df['ID'].shift().isin(items_before) & df['ID'].isin(specific_items) &  df['ID'].shift(-1).isin(items_after)
m3 = df['ID'].shift(2).isin(items_before) & df['ID'].shift().isin(specific_items) & df['ID'].isin(items_after)

mask = (m1| m2 | m3)
df1 = df[mask]
print (df1)
    Time ID
0      1  A
1      1  Y
2      1  C
3      2  B
4      2  X
5      2  D
8      4  A
9      4  Y
10     4  D
```

Then is analyzed not matched rows for previous and after `Time`:

```
df2 = df[~mask]
print (df2)
    Time ID
6      3  B
7      3  X
11     5  Y
12     5  D

m11 = df2['ID'].isin(items_before) & df2['ID'].shift(-1).isin(specific_items)
m12 = df2['ID'].isin(specific_items) & df2['ID'].shift().isin(items_before)

m21 = df2['ID'].isin(specific_items) & df2['ID'].shift(-1).isin(items_after)
m22 = df2['ID'].isin(items_after) & df2['ID'].shift().isin(specific_items)

# Notify when no preceding item 
for t in df2.loc[m11| m12, 'Time'].unique():
    print(f'No subsequent item found for: Time {t}')

for t in df2.loc[m21| m22, 'Time'].unique():
    print(f'No previous item found for: Time {t}')

No subsequent item found for: Time 3
No previous item found for: Time 5
```

If need solution for test per groups by `Time`:

```
df = df[df['ID'].isin(items_before + items_after + specific_items)]

m1 = df['ID'].isin(items_before) & df.groupby('Time')['ID'].shift(-1).isin(specific_items) & df.groupby('Time')['ID'].shift(-2).isin(items_after)
m2 = df.groupby('Time')['ID'].shift().isin(items_before) & df['ID'].isin(specific_items) &  df.groupby('Time')['ID'].shift(-1).isin(items_after)
m3 = df.groupby('Time').shift(2)['ID'].isin(items_before) & df.groupby('Time')['ID'].shift().isin(specific_items) & df['ID'].isin(items_after)

mask = (m1| m2 | m3)
df1 = df[mask]
print (df1)

df2 = df[~mask]
print (df2)

m11 = df2['ID'].isin(items_before) & df2.groupby('Time')['ID'].shift(-1).isin(specific_items)
m12 = df2['ID'].isin(specific_items) & df2.groupby('Time')['ID'].shift().isin(items_before)

m21 = df2['ID'].isin(specific_items) & df2.groupby('Time')['ID'].shift(-1).isin(items_after)
m22 = df2['ID'].isin(items_after) & df2.groupby('Time')['ID'].shift().isin(specific_items)

# Notify when no preceding item 
for t in df2.loc[m11| m12, 'Time'].unique():
    print(f'No subsequent item found for: Time {t}')

for t in df2.loc[m21| m22, 'Time'].unique():
    print(f'No previous item found for: Time {t}')
```

Comment: You are such a showoff with all your cool tricks :). Just kidding. never thought about using or to get the True statement. Cool stuff. Thx Joe

Comment: Don't fortget to also actually remove the offending rows ;-)